# flutter cache manager doesn't cache

Tags: flutter

I am simply trying to use cache manager! I created one :

```
Config(
  key,
  stalePeriod: const Duration(hours: 7),
  maxNrOfCacheObjects: 50,
  repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: key),
  fileService: HttpFileService(),
),
```

);

And then I am trying to use it:

```
(await instance.getSingleFile(uri.toString(), headers: headers)).readAsBytes();
```

`Uri` is an instance of Uri class which I have constructed.

The problem is, it seems it never returns the cached version. It always goes to the internet to fetch the file.

I tried reading the code, but couldn't find out how and when it is updating `validTill` property. It always return a `validTill` which is in the past.